# Android Google Maps Fragment crashes

Tags: android, maps

I have embedded Google Maps V2 in my App, as the Google Tutorial says.

I get the following errors, when switching to the map fragment.

```
03-08 12:52:01.600: E/AndroidRuntime(30314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)

03-08 12:52:01.600: E/AndroidRuntime(30314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-08 12:52:01.600: E/AndroidRuntime(30314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs/de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.StartActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.StartActivity
```

Heres the source code

```
package de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import data.Device;
import data.Mission;
import de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.R;
import logic.FetchData;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MapFrag extends MapFragment {

    protected FetchData thread;
    protected Device device;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View lView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container,
                false);

        return lView;

    }

    public void setDumb() {

    }

    public Device getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(Device device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

}


            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/map"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <permission
        android:name="de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapFrag"
            android:label="Map"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="removed" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you included your `de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.StartActivity` Activity inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` for your project?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.StartActivity in mainfest ??

Comment: Your `MapFrag` is not an activity, try removing it from your manifest.

Comment: now i get this error
03-08 13:08:36.740: E/ActivityThread(30729): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

General Question: Is it possible to display a map in a Fragment used in an actionbar or do i have to use an activity?

Comment: In the activity that you are using the `MapFrag` fragment are you extending `FragmentActivity`? Could you posts the Activity? I'd also recommend removing your Maps API key from the manifest you posted in the question!

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you, it had something to do with manifest.

Comment: No problem. Could you post your solution as an answer for others who have a similar problem in the future?

Comment: Could you post the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

change

`android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>`
to

`android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>` in **activity_main.xml**

and change

`public class MainActivity extends Activity`

to 
`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` in **MainActivity.java**

these two fixes worked for me.